# Credit Memo "Issue Refund Online" Pulls Payment To Customer from which Payment Source?

Tags: magento2, refund

When refunding an order and creating a credit memo on Magento 2.0, will it pull finances through the payment gateway the customer originally purchased through? An example is we had customer that paid for a product through our Paypal Express gateway. We need to cancel and refund the order. If I select "refund online" in credit memo, will it refund the customer through paypal express automatically not authorize.net or any of the other payment options we have available?

I am trying to double check where Magento sends funds through and if it gives me the option to select where they come from. We would like our refunds to come from where the payment option the customer selected and used.

Any pointers or information would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you do an online refund in Magento, customers will always be refunded through the same gateway they used to pay for the order.

Generally refunds have to be 'linked' to the original capture transaction (not to mention the customer's credit card), so nothing else would even be possible.